# Make full width image centered in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a div container that has a max height of 400 pixels. I'm placing a pretty large image inside the container. Since the container has a max height it's obviously cutting off most of the picture, which is what I'm aiming for. But my only issue is trying to get the image to center inside the div, so the main part of the picture is shown.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
<div class="headerimg">
<img src="www.jpg.com"/>
</div>

.headerimg { max-height: 400px; overflow: hidden; }
.header img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Comment: Post your code and show what you've tried.

Comment: Horizontal or vertical centering? (or both)?

Comment: Or JSFiddle can be useful.

Comment: try this way http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/prdBb/1/

Comment: @drew_w I think we can assume vertical, since a full-width image is centered by definition

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abzWz/1/ resize & center inside a div as background. replace contain with cover if you want to crop.

Comment: @JordanForeman From what I know, the default horizontal alignment depends on "position" (absolute/relative, etc), "text-align" and a few other css properties on the parent as well. I don't like to make assumptions about what the OP has chosen to do with their CSS...

Comment: @JordanForeman I've updated the post with my code.

Comment: @Dondada What about the jsfiddle i presented? http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/prdBb/1/

Comment: @PedroEstrada I can't use the background selector in CSS. If you see the code above I'm placing the img inside the div with an image tag.

Comment: @Dondada This way is ok? http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/enhLc/

Comment: @PedroEstrada thats much closer. I forgot to mention i'm using bootstrap and have an img-responsive class that adds max-width: 100% to the image and an auto height.

Comment: @Dondada - I believe [this is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16642842/1846192) you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
div.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
div.container img {
    max-height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple use**   : text-align:center

[**live example is here >>>>**](http://jsfiddle.net/zTNzS/1/)

```
div{
  max-height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;    
  text-align:center;
}
div img{
  height:500px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Comment: what is happening there did u see the jsfiddle page ?