# Keep image in the middle with css

Tags: html, css, image

I want an `<img>` tag to be exactly 100% width of the browser window when loading, but when the window is resized (down to mobile width), the image stays in the dead center of the window, remains the same size and the edges are cut off. Can you do this using just css? If so, how?

Comment: Remains the same size? You mean as it is on a desktop size screen?

Comment: Yes, not be resized. So only the middle part is visible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830735/center-image-in-div-with-overflow-hidden

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think this is the same effect as the OP is trying to achieve, on that solution the image does not stay centered.

Comment: then perhaps this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344169/center-image-in-a-div-too-small-for-it?rq=1 However it woudl make much more sense to substitute the image for a div and use the image as a bg image of that div as you suggested,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this is to set a `div` with a `background-image` and `background-position: center`, this will achieve the desired effect.

```
div {
    background: url([imageurl]) no-repeat top center;
    width: 100%;
    height: [imageheight];
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFV4a/)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using `background-size: cover` for these sorts of occasions.

```
html { 
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

(as taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/))

Comment: But remember, this is an image tag, not a background image. It is only at the top of the page. I am already using another image (small logo with background-repeat) as my background

Comment: @MarcoPrins Then replace the `<img>` with a `<div>` which has the image as a background. You can use the background property on multiple elements

Comment: or use a double background image